# Rotation Of Line Of Apsides

Tags: orbit, sun-synchronous

Why does the [line of apsides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apse_line) rotate in the plane of the orbit ? In case of a sun synchronous orbit does it have any effect on imaging accuracy or quality?

Comment: Did you try googling this?  The first five results I got all look pretty good.

Comment: @Soumajit Why don't you post it as the answer to this question then?  Then it won't show up in the "Unanswered" questions list.  (You could also potentially earn a badge).